# Как передвигаться виджет (картинку/кнопку) при нажатии кнопки в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, анимация, qlabel, qpushbutton

Как при нажатии на кнопку двигать кнопку или картинку? В моем случае кнопку.

Мой код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Button(QPushButton):
    mouseMoved = pyqtSignal()
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.mouseMoved.emit()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.btn1 = QPushButton(self)
        self.btn1.setMouseTracking(True);
        self.btn1.setText("Вперед")
        self.btn1.setStyleSheet("background-color: pink; border-radius: 14px;}")
        self.btn1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn1.resize(300, 150)
        self.btn1.move(450, 1000)
        self.show()
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = MainWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Button(QPushButton):

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            print('press LeftButton')
        elif event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            # сохранить положение щелчка,  
            # чтобы сохранить его постоянным при перетаскивании
            self.mousePos = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() != QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            return
           
        mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
        byteArray = QtCore.QByteArray()
        stream = QtCore.QDataStream(byteArray, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
        
        # установите objectName и положение щелчка, чтобы отслеживать виджет, 
        # который мы перемещаем, и его положение щелчка, чтобы гарантировать, 
        # что он будет перемещен соответственно
        stream.writeQString(self.objectName())
        stream.writeQVariant(self.mousePos)
        
        # создать пользовательский формат mimeData 
        # для сохранения информации о перетаскивании
        mimeData.setData('myApp/QtWidget', byteArray)
        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        
        # добавить растровое изображение виджета, чтобы показать, 
        # что на самом деле движется
        drag.setPixmap(self.grab())
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        
        # установите точку доступа в соответствии с положением нажатия мыши
        drag.setHotSpot(self.mousePos - self.rect().topLeft())
        drag.exec_()        


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()                          # !!! +++
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)                         # !!! +++
        
#        self.btn1 = QPushButton(self)
        self.btn1 = Button(centralWidget, objectName='pushButton')   # !!! +++
        
        self.btn1.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.btn1.setText("Нажмите ПКМ \nи \nперетащите кнопку")
        self.btn1.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: pink;  
            border-radius: 14px;
        """)
        self.btn1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn1.resize(300, 150)
        self.btn1.move(200, 150)
        
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)                                    # !!! +++
        
    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        # принимайте только наш формат mimeData, 
        # игнорируя любой другой контент данных
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat('myApp/QtWidget'):
            event.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        stream = QtCore.QDataStream(event.mimeData().data('myApp/QtWidget'))
        
        # Объекты QDataStream должны читаться в том же порядке, 
        # в котором они были написаны
        objectName = stream.readQString()
        
        # найти дочерний виджет, для которого установлено имя объекта 
        # в событии перетаскивания
        widget = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QWidget, objectName)
        
        if not widget:
            return
            
        # переместите виджет относительно исходной позиции мыши, 
        # чтобы он располагался точно там, где пользователь перетаскивает его,
        # и в соответствии с исходной позицией щелчка
        widget.move(event.pos() - stream.readQVariant())
       

if __name__ == "__main__":        
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.resize(700, 400)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> Вы немного не так поняли, мне нужно, что бы при нажатии какая либо другая кнопка передвигалась в другое место, (допустим по выражению x = 1000 x += 100)

Попробуйте так

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QPoint, QPropertyAnimation, \
    QParallelAnimationGroup
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, \
    QPushButton, QFrame, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap


class Form(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.resize(150, 150)
# установите свое изображение    -->  vvvvvv
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap("Ok.png").scaled(150, 150))
        self.label.move(20, 20)
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QFrame {
                background-color: orange;
            }
        """)
        self.button = QPushButton("Start Animation", self)
        self.button.resize(self.button.sizeHint())
        self.button.move(20, 300)
        self.define_animation()
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.frame_anim.start)

    def define_animation(self):
        self.frame_anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.label, b"geometry")
        self.frame_anim.setDuration(1000)
        self.frame_anim.setStartValue(self.label.geometry())
        self.frame_anim.setKeyValueAt(
            0.75, QRect(QPoint(20, 100), self.label.size()))
        self.frame_anim.setKeyValueAt(
            1, QRect(QPoint(380, 220), self.label.size()))
        self.frame_anim.finished.connect(self.define_new_animation)
        
    def define_new_animation(self):
        self.frame_anim.setKeyValues({}) 
        self.frame_anim.setStartValue(
            QRect(QPoint(380, 220), self.label.size()))
        self.frame_anim.setEndValue(
            QRect(QPoint(20, 220), self.label.size()))


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Form()
    w.resize(600, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы немного не так поняли, мне нужно, что бы при нажатии какая либо другая кнопка передвигалась в другое место, (допустим по выражению x = 1000 x += 100)

Comment: Да, это решает мою проблему, но вопрос, возможно ли как то реазиловать что бы каждый раз при нажатии кнопки картинка двигалась например на 100 пикселей в другую сторону

Comment: @TFader, да, все возможно. Мои ответы для вас полезны?

Comment: Все ваши ответы решают какие либо мои проблемы, и если возможно, то задать новый вопрос?

Comment: @TFader, если мои ответы помогают вам решать проблемы и учат чему-то новому, то не забудьте пометить их и как полезные. Да, вы можете задать новый вопрос, но код должен быть с конкретными виджетами и четко напишите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.